# AJAX firing ERROR function even though Response status is 200 OK

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I don't understand why this is returning the Error function from AJAX.  I had it working a few days ago and I don't know how it's failing now. I even super simplified my code to try to fire the success and rebuild the rest.

This is my Jquery:

```js
$("#results").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.URL.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      ajaxval: "A"
    },
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      alert("success");
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("fail");
    }
  });
});
```

This is my PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


<?php

$ajaxnum = $_POST['ajaxval'];

echo $ajaxnum;
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Seems super simple, Please let me know if I'm somehow missing something.  Like I said I had a much more complex php returning an html table by way of echoing rows back from a mySQL query result using a loop, etc.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the devtool?

Comment: error reporting and check your console

Comment: is the request coming from the same domain? - as suggested already, devtools / console - wealth of information for developers can be gained from these simple tools present in all good browsers

Comment: added screenshots from the chrome dev tool, click enter img description here

Comment: no console output in your screenshot

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load "URL". No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin "URLoriginal" is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: sorry just did the devtool, this is the error. I hadn't seen the console error reporting before, pretty new to this kind of programming

Comment: google that error .... you will find lots of results

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource one of many hits.

Comment: I'm trying to include it in the header, though I'm not 100% sure why I need it since it is coming from the same domain.  and it was working a few days ago without this header.  but here is the error when I try to put "header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); " at the top of my php.  I get this error          Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at -URL-/phptestcond.php:38) in /-URL-/phptestcond.php on line 38

Comment: Ok I got it, damn that was finnicky.  Allowed the origin at the top of the php.  Thank you to everyone who herded me towards an answer.  I'm trying to rapidly sponge up alot of this stuff, and everyone here is an awesome resource!

Comment: `www.domain.com` is not the same as `domain.com` - you'll see in your screenshot that the URL requested is `www.buildababe.biz` and the referrer is `buildababe.biz`